# Java How can i monitor something constantly without 100% CPU load?

Tags: java, while-loop, monitor, wait

Can i just use a while loop in conjunction with wait() and notify()/notifyall() ?

**EDIT: 
I want the else condition of the waitfornextprice method to only execute on the method putPrice occuring.**

```
public synchronized void putPrice(String s,int i) {
     if (getPrice(s) != i){
         this.Prices.put(s, i);
         notify();
     } 
}

public synchronized int waitForNextPrice(String s) {
    int b = null;
    if (hasPriceChanged(s)==true){
        b = getPrice(s);
    }
    else{
        //Need to block here, until putPrice() is called again
        while(hasPriceChanged(s)==false) wait();

        //Once putPrice has been called, b = getPrice();
        b = getPrice(s);
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the thing you're trying to monitor is capable of calling `notify`/`notifyAll`, that's the typical way of doing it, yes.

If it can't notify you, you could poll instead... but a "push" notification with `wait`/`notify` is preferable.

Answer (score 3):

You can also loop with a small Sleep() in the loop and it will bring your CPU usage from 100% to near 1%. Just add a Sleep(50); in your loop

Comment: Using sleep is quite a bad idea. As a rule of the thumb having sleep (and not waiting for interrupt, i.e. the main way to exit sleep being interrupt)  shows some problem w/ the code/design.

Comment: I totally agree, it depends on what he is monitoring and if he can be interrupted, or not.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a **java.util.Timer** instead of an expensive loop?

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a better way than using wait/notify.  Can you explain what you are trying to do and perhaps we can suggest alternatives, e.g. using the concurrency library in Java.

A much better structure is to use event driven processing.  When the price changes you want specific actions to occur.  You should trigger those actions from a price change.

```
public void putPrice(String s,int i) {
  if (getPrice(s) == i) return;
  prices.put(s, i);
  List<Runnable> onChange = priceListeners.get(s);
  if (onChange==null) return;
  for(Runnable run: onChange) run.run();
}
```

Instead of using Runnable you could create an interface which is notified which key/price changed.  This way you can have any number of prices change with just one thread. (Or a small number of threads as you choose)

Comment: Hi Peter, i like the sound of your answer but to be honest i dont really think i understand all of it.